# Philosophy of safety by Double Insulation

Tags: mains, safety, low-voltage

In a Class I appliance, when a fault occurs that brings dangerous voltage in contact with accessible conductive parts, the installation wiring fuse or GFCI will not only shut down the dangerous voltage, but they will also *make users aware of the fault condition*, so it could be resolved.

I find the latter bit rather important. For Class II equipment, a fault of one layer of insulation will instead turn the appliance into a Class 0 appliance *that keeps working completely normally*. A subsequent failure of the second layer, would expose dangerous voltage to users.

Is this "flaw" basically accepted as being too rare to matter, perhaps for lack of better alternatives or does Class II imply some means of making users aware of single insulation failure that I have not noticed?

Comment: It was never about the insulation's failure.  It had to do with AC and not running that through the outer shell on a 2-prong connection.  Insulation on wires that carry AC voltages failing is a more likely scenario as it's usually weaker than appliance casing.

Comment: Second layer of the insulation is the case of the product. Fault would mean it's broken open and live wires are falling out. I don't think someone smashing open a product and then reaching into the wiring is a major concern, people usually understand that they need to unplug broken equipment before poking it.

Comment: @user1850479 It could be cracked open at the backside. Say a plastic case adapter is strapped against a pole pressing a gap in its rear open. When you take it off the pole, it looks fine. Of course this is exceedingly unlikely... My question is: are these "made up" scenarios deemed too rare to matter?

Comment: When you look at class II devices, they're usually encapsulated in solid plastic, and getting to the wiring involves a hammer or saw. If you have a device where mains voltage could be exposed without the casing being broken then I think you don't really have Class II device (not sure about that though).